# Is it possible to print only stdout to the screen while writing stdout and stderr to a logfile?

Tags: bash, io, io-redirection

I know that it is possible to redirect both to a specific file:

```sh
./command 1> out.log 2> err.log
```

or

```sh
./command 1>test.log 2>&1
```

to write both to a file. But I don't know a way to write both to the same file (preserving the output order) while printing just one of both. `tee` isn't very helpful because it prints both file descriptors.

Comment: So both to a file, but only one or the other to, say, the terminal?

Comment: @chepner yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Writing standard output to one file and both to another is fairly simple with `tee`:

```
{ cmd | tee stdout.log; } &> both.log
```

Both descriptors of the compound command are redirected to `both.log`, but the standard output of `cmd` is first passed through `tee` to `stdout.log` before also being written to `both.log`.

Writing standard error to one and both to another is trickier.

```
{ foo 2>&1 1>&3 | tee stderr.log ; } 3>&1 | tee both.log > /dev/null
```

It's a little tricky to describe correctly. First, the command group's standard error is ignored; it's standard output is the pipe to `tee both.log`. But `3>&1` also copies its fd 3 to its standard output. So the question is, what gets written to that?

Inside the command group, `foo`'s standard output is the pipe to `tee stderr.log`. The `2>&1` copies `tee's` standard error to that descriptor, and `1>&3` copies `foo's` standard output to the inherited fd 3.

Comment: Okay that works, but I wanted stdout to be printed on the console. Which file fd 3 belongs to? Am I allowed to do redirections to arbitary file descriptors? (which may not point to a file)

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to write them to different files, in this case it will be very easy:

```
cmd 2>/stderr.log| tee -a stdout.log
```

But if you want a single file, you will need some tricks here and additional process running for redirection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use several redirections:

```
foo () { echo 1 ; echo 2 >&2 ; }
(( foo | tee >(cat) >&3) &>log ) 3>&1
```

The tee command sends the stdout to file descriptors 1 (through the *process substitution*) and 3. Both stdout and stderr are redirected to the log. In the end, 3, the copy of stdout, is sent back to the terminal.

Alternatively, you can do without the process substitution, redirect the output directly to log, but use `-a` and `>>` for append. You need to clear the log beforehand.

```
: > log; (( foo | tee -a log >&3) 2>> log ) 3>&1
```

Comment: This writes the following error to the log file `tee: /dev/fd63: Not a directory`

Comment: It works for me. What bash version on what OS are you using?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.4.19(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)    (mingw on Windows)

Comment: What about `:>log; (( foo | tee -a log >&3) 2>> log ) 3>&1`?

Comment: That works ! Nice, but I think that does not preseve the output order. 2 is written before 1 and what about  alternating outputs like 1 2 1 2 1.

Comment: I would be surprised if any solution preserved the order.

Answer (score 1):

stdout to the console and stdout and error to a file?

```
{ cmd | tee /dev/tty; } &> /tmp/both.log
```

Comment: Wow, that is pretty easy, but I wasn't sure if it's okay to access the terminal directly. That if I want to print stderr instead of stdout on the terminal and write both to a log file. I think this is not that easy like this, is it?

Comment: a bit more complicated but possible: `{ cmd 2> >(tee /dev/tty); } &> /tmp/both.log`

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question :

stderr to the console and stdout and error to a file?

```
{ cmd 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee /dev/tty; } &> /tmp/both.log
```

`3>&1 1>&2 2>&3` means swapping stdout and stderr